# Is it possible to set up URL Rewrite rules in IIS in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

URL Rewrite extension for IIS will install without error on Windows Server 2016 but does not seem to work, the icon does not appear in IIS `inetmgr.exe`.

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.   Reinstall. Reboot. The latest URL Rewrite installer for Windows Server 2012 R2 still works with IIS in Windows Server 2016.